# How to cross join unnest a JSON array in Presto

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, presto

Given a table that contains a column of JSON like this:

```
{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"}, {"type":"a","value":"8"}]}
{"payload":[{"type":"c","value":"7"}, {"type":"b","value":"3"}]}
```

How can I write a Presto query to give me the average `b` value across all entries?

So far I think I need to use something like Hive's [lateral view explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode), whose equivalent is [cross join unnest](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html#use-unnest-to-expand-arrays-and-maps) in Presto.

But I'm stuck on how to write the Presto query for `cross join unnest`.

How can I use `cross join unnest` to expand all array elements and select them?

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example of that

```sql
with example(message) as (
VALUES
(json '{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}'),
(json '{"payload":[{"type":"c","value":"7"}, {"type":"b","value":"3"}]}')
)


SELECT
        n.type,
        avg(n.value)
FROM example
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_EXTRACT(message,'$.payload')
                    as ARRAY(ROW(type VARCHAR, value INTEGER))
                    )
                ) as x(n)
WHERE n.type = 'b'
GROUP BY n.type
```

`with` defines a common table expression (CTE) named `example` with a column aliased as `message`

`VALUES` returns a verbatim table rowset

`UNNEST` is taking an array within a column of a single row and returning the elements of the array as multiple rows.

`CAST` is changing the `JSON` type into an `ARRAY` type that is required for `UNNEST`. It could easily have been an `ARRAY<MAP<` but I find `ARRAY(ROW(` nicer as you can specify column names, and use dot notation in the select clause.

`JSON_EXTRACT` is using a jsonPath expression to return the array value of the `payload` key

`avg()` and `group by` should be familiar SQL.

Comment: The question specifies Presto, however if using Athena, it appears casting to `ARRAY(ROW(` and some other complex types is not supported, so use `ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR))` instead and in the select and group by clause refer to values like `x.n['type']` etc

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, this was finally implemented in Presto 0.79. :)

Here is an example of the syntax for the cast from [here](https://github.com/facebook/presto/issues/2154):

```
select cast(cast ('[1,2,3]' as json) as array<bigint>);
```

Special word of advice, there is no 'string' type in Presto like there is in Hive.
That means if your array contains strings make sure you use type 'varchar' otherwise you get an error msg saying 'type array does not exist' which can be misleading.

```
select cast(cast ('["1","2","3"]' as json) as array<varchar>);
```

Comment: Value cannot be cast to array(varchar)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was running an old version of Presto.

`unnest` was added in version 0.79

https://github.com/facebook/presto/blob/50081273a9e8c4d7b9d851425211c71bfaf8a34e/presto-docs/src/main/sphinx/release/release-0.79.rst