# Presto unnest json

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, presto

follwing this question: [how to cross join unnest a json array in presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932950/how-to-cross-join-unnest-a-json-array-in-presto)

I tried to run the example provided but 
I get and error while doing so

the SQL command:

```
select x.n
from
unnest(cast(json_extract('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"}, 
{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}','$.payload') as array<varchar>)) as  x(n)
```

the error I got:

`Value cannot be cast to array<varchar>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: string is null`

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},  {"type":"a","value":"8"}]}','$.payload')`

gives:

`[{"type":"b","value":"9"},  {"type":"a","value":"8"}]`

which is `ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR,VARCHAR>>`.
you can change your query to:

  `SELECT x.n
  FROM
  UNNEST (CAST(JSON_EXTRACT('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}','$.payload') AS ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>)) AS x(n)`

Comment: I run your suggestion and it seems to partially work.
in order to separate the map's value I had to explicitly pick the values of the map :
`
SELECT x.n['type']as "type",x.n['value']as "value"
  FROM
  UNNEST (CAST(JSON_EXTRACT('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}','$.payload') AS ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>)) AS x(n)`
is there alternative direct approach?

Comment: Another alternative, you can use x(type,value) like this :::  SELECT **type, value** FROM UNNEST(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT( '{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}' ,'$.payload' ) as ARRAY(ROW(type VARCHAR, value VARCHAR)) ) ) as **x(type,value)**;

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSON_EXTRACT,CAST and finally UNNEST to respective columns

```
SELECT type,value FROM 
UNNEST(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"}, 
                          {"type":"a","value":"8"}]}'
                         ,'$.payload'
                 ) as ARRAY(ROW(type VARCHAR, value VARCHAR)
            )
       )
) as x(type,value)
```

gives output as below

```
 type | value
------+-------
 b    | 9
 a    | 8
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible interpretation of the return datatype is the following:

```
ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR,VARCHAR>>
```

but has the downside that accessing values in a map can't be done using dot notation.

An alternative datatype to assume would be this:

`ARRAY(ROW(type VARCHAR, value VARCHAR))`

Which resembles the `ARRAY<STRUCT<` Hive datatype equivalent.

**Massive digression here>>** JSON is a bit ambiguous.

Which one is correct? Is a JSON object a representation of a map ( hashmap, dictionary, key-value pairs whatever your language calls it) or is it more like a struct (object, class, bag of names properties whatever your language calls it)? It originates from JavaScript ( Object Notation) intended to cater for arrays, objects and primitive types, but more widespread usage means it has ambiguous mapping (ha) in other languages. Perhaps functionally equivalent but in theory the `MAP` should be quicker for random reads/writes and the `ROW` probably has some extra object oriented overhead, but this is all implemented in Java where everything is an object anyway so I have no answer. Use whatever you like. **<< I digress.**

**You found this a bit verbose:**

```
SELECT 
x.n['type'] as "type",
x.n['value'] as "value"
FROM UNNEST (
            CAST(
                JSON_EXTRACT('{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}'
                             ,'$.payload') 
                AS ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>
                )
            ) 
        AS x(n)
```

**Here's the alternative**

```
SELECT
    n.type,
    n.value
FROM UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                            '{"payload":[{"type":"b","value":"9"},{"type":"a","value":"8"}]}'
                            ,'$.payload'
                            ) 
                as ARRAY(ROW(type VARCHAR, value VARCHAR))
                )
            ) as x(n)
```

It's just as verbose; the names of the columns are just shifted to the CAST expression, but perhaps (subjective!) easier to look at.