# Select particular values from JSON column in Presto

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have a JSON column `points` of type VARCHAR in a table which I want to parse in Presto. For example:

```
points = {"0": 0.2, "1": 1.2, "2": 0.5, "15": 1.2, "20": 0.7}
```

I want to select only the values for keys `"0", "2" and "20"`. How do I use the UNNEST functionality of Presto to get them. What I've done till now is:

`select t.value from myTable CROSS JOIN UNNEST(points) AS t(key, value) limit 1`

But this gives this error:

```
Cannot unnest type: varchar
```

`Update:`

I ran the following query and got the result but it is returning one random key-value pair from the JSON whereas I need specific keys.

`select key, value from myTable CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT_TO_MAP(points, ',', ':')) AS t(key, value) limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest an Array or Map. So you first need to convert the JSON string into a MAP:

```
CAST(json_parse(str) AS MAP<BIGINT, DOUBLE>)
```

Here is an example:

```
presto> select tt.value
     -> from (VALUES '{"0": 0.2, "1": 1.2, "2": 0.5, "15": 1.2, "20": 0.7}') as t(json)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(json) AS MAP<BIGINT, DOUBLE>)) AS tt(key, value)
     -> ;
 value
-------
   0.2
   1.2
   1.2
   0.5
   0.7
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cast to json datatype first according to these docs: [enter link description here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)

```
UNNEST(CAST(points AS JSON))
```

Full query:

```
select t.value from myTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(points AS JSON)) AS t(key, value) limit 1
```

Comment: What should be the full query?

Comment: I added it to the answer, let me know how it goes

Comment: I tried this but this also didn't work:

select t.value from myTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(JSON CAST(points AS JSON) AS MAP(INTEGER, REAL))) AS t(key, value) limit 1

Comment: ahh, `unnest` is expecting an array, see if you can cast your json payload to an array

Comment: Maybe: `select t.value from myTable
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(CAST(points AS JSON) AS ARRAY<VARCHAR>) AS t(key, value) limit 1`

Comment: See these two answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496811/presto-unnest-json and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932950/how-to-cross-join-unnest-a-json-array-in-presto