# Presto unnest json map

Tags: json, hadoop, presto

Following these posts: [How to cross join unnest a JSON array in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932950/how-to-cross-join-unnest-a-json-array-in-presto) and [Presto unnest json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496811/presto-unnest-json)
I am unable to map my JSON into desired table.

When I run this presto:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM UNNEST(
        CAST(
            JSON_EXTRACT('{"1":{"a":10,"b":11},"2":{"a":20,"b":21}}', '$.1') AS ARRAY(
                VARCHAR
                -- ROW(VARCHAR, BIGINT)
                -- MAP(VARCHAR, MAP(VARCHAR, BIGINT))
            )
        )
    ) AS x(n)
```

I get :

```
(INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT) Cannot cast to array(varchar). Expected a json array, but got {
{"a":10,"b":11} ...
```

But my ideal intended answer is:

```
  a | b
 ---+---
 10 | 11
 20 | 21
```

How do I `UNNEST` a `Map` and not an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct json path for your goal would be `$.*` but wildcards [are not supported by presto](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7005), so you can cast your json to map of maps and work with that:

```
SELECT maps['a'] a, maps['b'] b
FROM (UNNEST(map_values(
        CAST(JSON '{"1":{"a":10,"b":11},"2":{"a":20,"b":21}}' AS MAP(VARCHAR , MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER)))))) as tmp(maps);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about `MAP_VALUES` keyword.

Comment: @vishwarajanand was glad to help! There are a lot of useful functions, check out the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions.html).